# Speed of development - Asp.net vs Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, webforms

I am trying to evaluate whether we should migrate from developing our product in ASP.net web forms (current technology) to Silverlight. I remember reading that silverlight development can add to development speed, so this is the main driver for me to think about this.

I am assuming that business logic development will take same amount of time, I am open to it if UI development speed will bring in significant benefits.

The App we have is a line of business data driven app. There are very few rich reports required, however the printable data reports need a lot of formatting (since the app is highly configurable in terms of data setup; for eg which columns have a merged header and then sub headers, which cells to show data in red, etc). Apart from this most of the UI is Asp.net webfrms for entering data.

Do you see any significant improvement we can achieve by moving to silverlight? We also need to consider time to migrate existing UI and the learning curve, but if that were not a constraint, what would be your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see you gaining a lot using Silverlight, especially with the awesome charting controls that are available. This is compounded with how easy RIA services makes creating data driven applications. That said, it really depends on your development team. If they are already familiar with Silverlight I would go for it, but if they are not be wary that initially it may be slower than if you were working with ASP.Net.

Comment: As I said there are very few rich reports, like charts - most are mainly data driven reports, things that are quite common in lob applications. It is for these functionality that I am asking if Silverlight will get any benefits.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an either or situation. You can use a Silverlight app from within your ASP.NET webForms app. So you could develop some functionality using Silverlight while leveraging your existing codebase and effort.

The two work hand in hand.

Comment: I understand that, but I am asking whether having Silverlight forms for eg will be faster to develop than ASP.net web forms.

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question. You started by saying "migrate" :). Anyway, you and your team will be faster in the tools/technologies you are familiar with. If you've not done WPF or Silverlight before, if will be a huge learning curve. And getting the app to look real nice will be anther huge effort.

Comment: :) sorry for the confusion - but I was speaking of migrating our dev efforts, not the entire product itself. Anyways thanks for your inputs.